# Textbox loses its value on button Click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a texbox which is read only. The value comes from another textbox. But when I click on the submit button, the value of textbox goes blank.

Please see the code of textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalAmt" runat="server" class="txtfld-popup2" MaxLength="5"  ReadOnly="true" EnableViewState= "false"></asp:TextBox>
```

Also please see the code of page load and button click:

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radiobtnIsCustomer.Checked && txt_custId.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        div_errorMsg.InnerText = "Please enter your Customer Id.";
        return;
    }
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        SendMail();
        Response.Redirect("ThankYou_AgriBusiness.html"); 
    }
    if (!CaptchaControl1.IsValid)
    {
        lblCaptchaError.Text = "Invalid Captcha";
    }
    Customer newCustomer = new Customer();
    newCustomer.IsExistingCustomer = radiobtnIsCustomer.Checked;
    newCustomer.ExistingCustomerId = txt_custId.Text;
}
```

Code for Page load:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblCaptchaError.Text = "";
    div_errorMsg.InnerText = "";
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        txtTotalAmt.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from States_agri", conn);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        ddl_state.DataSource = dr;
        ddl_state.Items.Clear();
        ddl_state.DataTextField = "StateName";
        ddl_state.DataValueField = "StateID";
        ddl_state.DataBind();
        ddl_state.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select State--", "0"));
        conn.Close();

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        rm = new ResourceManager("Resources.Strings", System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("App_GlobalResources"));
        ci = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        LoadString(ci); 
    }
}
```

Comment: EnableViewState= "false" - that'd do it.

Comment: I did it that also, still not working

Comment: You removed that text?

Comment: yes, i removed coz it was not working..I did it with EnableViewState= "true". but the result was same. Not working

Comment: where are you setting the text for this textbox ?

Comment: Acutally, i want this text for getting the data to an email when client's submit the button. But when the user clicks the textbox refreshes and becomes null

Comment: your answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/24247162/941398 the problem is the ReadOnly attribute.

Comment: @user3751568 How does txtTotalAmt get filled? It initially is rendered as readonly. Please upload the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that ReadOnly property. Don't do this.

```
ReadOnly="true" EnableViewState= "false"
```

If you want to make it so that the user cannot alter the text on the client side, You could add an html property to the textbox to mark it readonly in your pageload.

```
txtTotalAmt.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly")
```

Comment: Thanks Eoin, really helped me.. :) have a great weekend

Comment: one more thing eoin, When I submit all the proper data and on button click it, first times it gives me invalid captcha error. Y, i dont know.